# SQL Query to fetch details from multiple tables using Group By and Join

Tags: sql-server, database, join, group-by

I always feel poor when it comes to SQL. I have two tables, say table revenue which has following structure:

```
Revenue Table
Clicks
impressions
ad_id
device_id
money_generated
date
```

Another table which has devices details as follows:

```
Devices
device_id
device_name
```

One more table say Ads..

```
Ads Table
ad_name
ad_id
----
```

Now what I want is to fetch sum of impressions, clicks, money generated by a particular device for a particular ad between a particular date.

I tried this query of linking revenue & device tables but failed.

```
select 
   device_name, 
   revenue.impressions, 
   revenue.clicks, 
   revenue.money_generated, 
   revenue.ad_id 
FROM
   (select
       device_id, 
       dim_ad_id,
       SUM(imp_count) as impressions,
       SUM(click_count) as clicks,
       SUM(money_generated) as revenue,
    from 
       revenue
    GROUP BY 
       ad_id
    GROUP BY 
       device_id
    WHERE 
       dim_Date>'2017-11-02 10:33:00' 
       and dim_date<'2017-11-08 00:56:22') revenue 
JOIN deviceTable as devices ON 
devices.device_id=revenue.device_id 
and devices.device_name IN ('ABC')
```

Please ignore the slight mistake of column names as i have renamed them before pasting it here. Please help me understanding the SQL better

Comment: Does the statement even run??  I'll be surprised if it doesn't error out.

Answer (score 1):

You have two GROUP BY clauses in that derived table which will throw a syntax error.

```
select 
   device_name, 
   revenue.impressions, 
   revenue.clicks, 
   revenue.money_generated, 
   revenue.ad_id 
FROM
   (select
       device_id, 
       dim_ad_id,
       SUM(imp_count) as impressions,
       SUM(click_count) as clicks,
       SUM(money_generated) as revenue,
    from 
       revenue
    GROUP BY 
       ad_id, device_id        --fixed syntax here
    WHERE 
       dim_Date>'2017-11-02 10:33:00' 
       and dim_date<'2017-11-08 00:56:22') revenue 
JOIN 
    deviceTable as devices ON 
    devices.device_id = revenue.device_id 
    and devices.device_name IN ('ABC')
LEFT JOIN 
    Ads on
    Ads.ad_id = revenue.dim_id --or what ever it should be
```

Comment: oh boy! my bad.. let me try and get back :) Thanks for quick reply. It is midnight here and this sqls are killing me

Comment: Bro.. great :) we have succesfully joined two tables,,, how do I join ad table now to fetch the ad info as well? Just one example shud be fine.. i will join the remaning 4-5 tables in similar way

Comment: Should I assume all the query given above as one virtual table and link it with our ad table? An example will explain all things

Comment: Where is the ad info stored?

Comment: Its in question. In a separate ad table. We have ad_id in revenue to map.

Comment: this is a simple join, which i added at the bottom

Comment: Great :) I think am done.  I have a last question for you. I can see some data is repeated however with different impressions & clicks count. Can you explain why?

Comment: I can not, since i do not have access to your data. But, I would suspect you have a one to many relationship on the ads --> devices.